# Teaching with LaTeX during a Pandemic: corrections on a file pdf

Tags: tools, mathjax, acrobat, latextools

I should correct my students' handwritten exercises that them send me with a `.pdf` file for *distance learning* due to the closure of schools in Italy and I don't know for how much longer. I'm using or directly **Adobe Reader** using the stick notes writing the mistakes in unicode characters or using this tool online named [pdfescape](https://www.pdfescape.com/).

Just for this tool pdfescape I use the free option. I unfortunately not having webcam and scanner I'm obliged always to write in `LaTeX` for the correction of the texts of my students of an high school. Before I write the right solution and I create the image with `LaTeX` and glue it into the `.pdf` file (see the tool **PDFescape** in the image belove).

[image]

I'm spending a lot of time on each of them and I'm asking you kindly if any of you know of any short routes, advice, anything that can make my correction in `LaTeX` faster.

I'm asking if there is a tool that opens `.pdf` and where I can write directly in `LaTeX` or **MathJaX** keeping my students' writing and overlaying my correction.

Thank you all very much and I hope that one day or recently exists a solution or more solutions.

Comment: I think ultimately you will go insane if you put so much efforts in the *visual appearance* of corrections. If you have a tablet, you can just draw/write on the scan and return it. True, this won't look as good as properly typeset formulae, but you will be much faster and have thus more time to set up the online lectures (assuming your instructions now also have to be online), and to make sure the quality of the content of the corrections is good.

Comment: pdf editing tools are off topic I think (and it seems a painful way to operate, can't you use google docs (or even office 365 or some such) that allows far more natural collaborative editing.  Oh or use overleaf and edit the tex source if your students are using tex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Usually in Italy people who work well and are not appreciated. I am doing everything possible to ensure the correction of many exercises both in Mathematics and Physics. Remember that it is difficult to operate in my condition and I am doing the best I can. I explained TeX in just one hour but only two are passionate about it. I use Google Classroom but there is not even an editor with LaTeX. Some students to destabilize pretend not to understand some of my characters. Then I send you a screenshot of my handwriting in chat. I'm looking for advice and empathic comprehension.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I've never particularly liked two aspects of life: the lie and the wickedness, especially the free one. I'm going to go into tilt and I can't find the shortest way: I'm without tablet, graphics tablet, webcam, I'm without sound board and this year I wanted to buy a good laptop. Obviously I can't write personal motivations but with all my heart I'm putting my soul, maximum effort but ... as it happens in Italy often we complain especially with those who work with seriousness and sense of responsibility. I wanted to write in LaTeX to avoid misunderstandings of my handwriting.

Comment: @Sebastiano Sorry, I did not mean to insult you or anything. I just wrote what I thought might make most sense in the current situation. All I want to say is that, in my humble opinion, now it is not the time to worry too much about the visual appearance of corrections that get attached to scans of handwritten answers by students.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat No, don't worry, I never thought you insulted me in the slightest. Students to do nothing write to you, but I don't understand the symbol, what it says, but that symbol what it is and they make me waste more time. I'm simply looking for help and not being shut the door in my face. Empathy and humanity are important.

Comment: @Sebastiano not online, but I am using a lot [xournalpp](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp). Six year ago I bought a simple bamboo tablet at less than 60€ and it was my best investment for classes. To remain in topic, xournalpp aloows you to add LaTeX formulas on the fly...

Comment: @Rmano Very kind Rmano. The coronavirus has complicated my work at least 10 times over. Among students are always those who destabilize others who want to work. I thank you for your valuable suggestion but I should first understand how it works :-) this xournalpp. If one day I won't be alive no flowers :-) but good works I'd recommend it. :-)

Comment: AFAIUI, [fancytooltips](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancytooltips) should allow one to use LaTeX code in tooltips, but I don't see the tooltips of the manual in Okular (maybe Acrobat Reader is needed?). No time to investigate. Okular allows one to conveniently annotate a PDF (in GUI mode). One [may insert LaTeX markup](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kdegraphics/okular/annotations.html) and Okular compiles+renders it, but AFAIK, only the source (TeX) code is saved to the PDF. So, this would only work if students have Okular and LaTeX... which I fear is not a realistic hypothesis.

Comment: [Sample note with LaTeX code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV4S5.png) I wrote and rendered in Okular.

Comment: Please leave this question open for a while, at least until @Sebastiano has found valuable feedback (the suggestions provided so far are already helpful!).
Being in the same country I know the struggle he's going through as a teacher, and the help on this SE site can be really helpful for him!
Leave the question open for a little longer than usual, given the exceptional circumstance that led him to post the question.

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin I have never hidden anything; when a man cries many people think he is weak, but all the opposite. My question is about to be closed and I assure you that I am going through a very bad time. Can you create a room and if possible we will speak in Italian with the consent of the moderators or the responsible people? I write very badly in English.  How do you make a room by inviting me?

Comment: @frougon Great !!!!!!!!! frougon .How does it work?

Comment: [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/) is a free software PDF viewer (it can handle other formats). It works on Linux and according to its home page also on other OSes, incl. Windows and macOS (I use it only on Linux). It has annotation features described [here](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kdegraphics/okular/annotations.html). LaTeX math code can be included there between pairs of `$$`. There is a button to click to render these formulas. I believe this uses a TeX distribution that has to be installed on the system (it worked automatically for me on Debian: I didn't have to enter any path).

Comment: @frougon frougon ...I will never be able to install it-- But is it free? If you'd describe the steps maybe I could but I use OS W7 and maybe it works under W10.

Comment: Annotations can be saved, but I don't know if the formulas can be saved in rendered form, as images (I don't want to give you false hopes). Yes, it is free, follow the link I gave...

Comment: @frougon Where I live, they say "he who lives on hope will die of hope." :-)

Comment: Hah! This happens... I can't say how to install Okular on Windows, but the official site has instructions on its [download page](https://okular.kde.org/download.php). KDE is a big thing (all free software), usually Linux-oriented, but they give a link to the Microsoft store, so maybe they managed to package it in an easy-to-install way?

Comment: @frougon Veri kind frougon I have seen with Alessandro Cuttin :-)..I think that it is to pay :-( (Microsoft store) :-(

Comment: The (at least Linux) [source code](https://cgit.kde.org/okular.git/tree) is available for free (the license appears to be a mix of GPL and LGPL), but turning it into a working executable with all its required environment (KDE) on Windows... I don't know.

Comment: @frougon :-( I not understood anything to install on Windows. Remember: thank you very much for the humble user like you. Any future help are welcome. Goodnight.

Comment: I like the `pdfreview` package (in TeX Live).  It’s not quick, but it’s quicker than the other methods I’ve tried.

Comment: @Thérèse I thank you and everyone who understands my emergency at this dramatic time. I don't know how to use this package. My question is closed and I would appreciate, not out of insistence, that it be reopened for any answers.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/89svfb2q4p1nbp5/pdfreview-example.tex?dl=0 is a little example of how I use `pdfreview` with luatex.

Comment: @Thérèse With all my heart, if I would have had the open question, I would have asked you how to upload a pdf of one of my students and correct it. It is sufficient to use pdfLaTeX with CM fonts instead of LuaLaTeX.

Comment: I’m not sure what your situation is, but if you don’t have TeX Live on the machine you’re using, I think Overleaf must have `pdfreview`, so that you could upload the `.pdf` among the project resources, the way you’d add a font or an image. You can use the package to comment on any kind of `.pdf`, not just those created with LaTeX, and you don’t have to use `luatex`.  But teaching online is no fun…

Comment: @Thérèse I use MikTeX on OS W7 and not TeX Live. Not only is it not fun but I also work an average of 10 hours a day. I'm so tired. I'm not logged on overleaf but it would be interesting to have an answer from you. Maybe I'll try. I have about 500 homework to correct and I don't even have time for myself.